# The resource is not on the build path of a javascript project

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, maven

I am making a javaEE project.
I imported a project from my computer as a maven project (Import->Import as maven project)
The project has many javascript files in the source folder.
Eclipse is not showing outline of my javascript files. '

However when i imported the project as a javascript project the outline was shown correctly!!

How can i make the outline correct when i import it as a maven project?

Comment: What package of Eclipse do you have (eg, Eclipse for Java Developers, Eclipse for Java EE Developers, etc)? Have you installed any other plug-ins or features?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just answered this for another question, very similar to yours.

You need to add the JavaScript "nature" to the project (basically, tell Eclipse to treat it as a JavaScript project). Right-click on the project and choose Configure > Convert to JavaScript Project....

[image]

After doing that you should see a Builder named "JavaScript Validator" and have the JavaScript section in the properties.

Comment: Right clicking on the project does not have a configure option. where is it?

Comment: Try this: Right-click on the project, choose 'Properties', look for the 'Project Facets' menu on the left.

Comment: @shivi I added a screen shot showing it in the Package Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...i was actually right clicking on the navigator!
eclipse does not have that good javascript support...aptana studio is much better

Comment: Convert to javascript project is not shown in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have `.js` files associated to Javascript Editor. Go to Window->Preferences-General -> Editors -> File Associations. Find the `"*.js"` entry, click on it, then click on `Javascript Editor` and click the Default button.

Comment: it is already default.
does it have something to do with the module pattern of javascript i am using.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in Eclipse Photon:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Edit the .project file adding the Javascript nature: *org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature*

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983263/716463)